# Why is foreign key being set here instead of just making a new migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay here's an example from CodeSchool, and they don't explain what the `foreign_key` option here is doing.

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :tweeter_id
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tweet, foreign_key: :tweeter_id
end
```

To me it looks like it is just trying to avoid creating a new migration to add the `tweeter_id` column to both models.

Question 2:

The foreign key on line 2 is going to be created on the `tweets` table and NOT the `locations` table, and the one on line 6 is for the `locations` table NOT the `tweets` table, right?

Answer (score 1):

To use a `has_one` relationship, you need to add on the database of the `belong_to` part an attribute. The rails standard for this case is `tweet_id`, but for one reason or another, the person who wrote this code didn't followed the standards. If you look on location table you should locate a column`tweeter_id`, which is used to point to the correct `tweet`.

Comment: So it IS a workaround to avoid creating a new migration and fixing the tables?

Comment: @dwilbank yes, change the name to the actual column which is being used to make the relationship, or just remove if is called `tweet_id`. I'm not sure how easy it is to find out on CodeSchool. Assuming you can't see the database, maybe you can see what are the migrations and guess what is it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question 2, the foreign key in BOTH places refers to a key in the Location model. The two definitions are related.

The 'has_one' is defining the foreign key in the "other" table.

The "belongs_to" is defining the foreign key in "this" table.

This is an illustration that you don't have to depend on the default (expected) foreign key of `tweet_id`

Since it works, the tables aren't "broken" and don't need to be "fixed" and it illustrates the flexibility of rails... although "convention over configuration" is still preferred where possible.

There is no foreign key in the Tweet table based on the classes you've provided.

Comment: Thanks. Going to cogitate on this one for a while. Got a few projects that might make it more clear for me.